Way to use same API to ask private and public docker registries about tags and digests
I'm trying to do some script that fetches info about docker image tags available and digests for specific tags. But I must have been missing something obvious because I cannot find same way to ask private registry like GCP Artifact Registry and Docker Hub for tags or manifests related to an docker image.
I found some docs about GCP registry here which basically points to docker registry docs which then points to CNCF Distribution spec which makes me think that GCP is not following v2 api spec.
In their auth example they use different path to fetch tags than in Docker Hub registry API spec. I've tested it and this path
/v2/my-gcp-projects/my-app/image-name/tags/list

returns my private image tags list in GCP. Also GCP example seems to be using correct API paths based on CNCF distribution spec.
I've tried same approach but with Docker Hub with public debian image. I'm using multiple hosts because this is what I found after asking google. I could not find Docker Hub registry API host in docs anywhere.
$ curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/library/debian/tags/list | head
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/debian","Action":"pull"}]}]}

$ curl -s https://index.docker.io/v2/library/debian/tags/list | head
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"library/debian","Action":"pull"}]}]}

$ curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/library/debian/tags/list | head
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>404 : Docker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    * {
        line-height: 1.2;

What is interesting this kind of works without any auth but based on paths it looks like different API than this from GCP:
curl https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/library/repositories/debian/tags

Is Docker Hub not using same API as GCP Registry?
Another thing, somehow I can run docker buildx imagetools inspect debian without any auth on Docker Hub, so do I need auth to public index or not really?
Can I somehow use same API both for GCP registry and Docker Hub and possibly other registries? What am I missing here?

The OCI distribution-spec covers the tag listing and manifest HEAD/GET APIs. From there, the digest is ideally included as a header or calculated from the body of the GET request.
The auth part you are getting stuck at isn't standardized by OCI yet (there's a working group assigned to that). However most registries implement either basic or bearer auth, which clients detect from the www-authenticate header in the 401 responses. The distribution project has a decent overview of the bearer token workflow at https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/auth/token/
There are quite a few implementations of this you can leverage to avoid reinventing the wheel. Some popular ones include crane from Google's go-containerregistry, oras from Microsoft, skopeo and their containers project from RedHat, and my own regclient project. These handle not only the auth, but also headers for the manifest APIs, and pagination of the tag listing. At least in my own regclient project, there's also support for credential helpers, fallback to GET requests when the digest isn't included with a HEAD, retry logic, and rate limit detection.

Thanks this helped a bit but still I spent hours figuring out correct way. Tried curl -iH "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -s 'https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/debian:pull' | jq -r '.token')" https://registry.docker.io/v2/library/debian/tags/list and other combinations, but this only returned 503 each time. Finally this worked: curl -iH "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -s 'https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/debian:pull' | jq -r '.token')" https://index.docker.io/v2/library/debian/tags/list.
